# Get only specific element node from xml using stax parser

Tags: java, xml, stax

```
<xml>
<name>steve</name>
<age>12</age>
<country>Germany</country>
<person>
  <college>kmu university</college>
  <country>Sweden</country>
</person>
</xml>
```

Using stax parser while parsing I get country name as Germany,Sweden. But I need only Sweden not germany. Any other way to get it.I am using STAX parser to parse this xml.

**Expected Output: Sweden**

**Actual Output:Germany,Sweden**

Comment: do you have to use STAX?

Comment: yes I have to use STAX because Xml content very large in size

Answer (score 3):

When you do StAX (and SAX) parsing, you need to track the context yourself.  this means you need to keep track of the elements which have started and not yet completed.  once you have this information, you can then keep only the "country" element which is nested under the "person" element and ignore all other "country" elements.

Comment: thanks how to get country element node only under person can you give some example...I dont want code just explain logic it is enough.

Comment: @BalaMurugan - i did explain the logic in my answer: "keep track of the elements which have started and not yet completed" and "keep only the "country" element which is nested under the "person" element"